# Unable to find element on closed window in IE-11, Windows 7-64 bit

Tags: automated-testing

I can't able to run script in IE11, where same works fine in firefox and Chrome.
I did change in protected mode settings, Zoom Level Setting 
By Default i have windows registry settings with ieexplorer.exe valued "0".
But still same issue occurs. Please provide solution to solve this issue

Code i have used:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability("InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION", true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
capabilities.setCapability("initialBrowserUrl",url));
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Please share exact error or try to change IE11 to IE Edge. Because as per selenium version changes they are moving to IE Edge only.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout

Comment: Above mention code missing the code which have path of IE Driver like: System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "pathofIEdriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
Might be due to that it is not identifying the browser and throwing error window not found.

Comment: sorry to mention.I have added system.set property also in my scripts

Answer (score 1):

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    capabilities.setCapability("InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION", true);
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
    capabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
    capabilities.setCapability("initialBrowserUrl","www.google.co.in");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.1.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Manoj Test");
```

Above code working fine on my system

1. Window 7 64 Bit
2. IE Driver is 3.1 64 Bit
3. IE version is:
   11.0.9600.18537

Please share code for debugging.

Comment: Rather than answering two times, Please use Edit option to improve your previous answer.